# Show current function in header line

Tags: programming

I have used a package before which used the header line to show the name of the current function being edited.  Whatever package it was, I don't have it installed now.  What are my options for getting this sort of functionality?

**How can I have a persistent view (e.g. mode-line, header-line, etc.) of the current function being edited when the top of the function is past the top of the window?**

Answer (score 11):

This sounds a lot like you've followed [this Emacs Redux blog post](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/04/05/which-function-mode/) which is using `which-func-mode`.  It explains its purpose (displaying the current function point is within), demonstrates how to enable and customize it and offers the following snippet to put the indicator in the header line:

```
;; Show the current function name in the header line
(which-function-mode)
(setq-default header-line-format
              '((which-func-mode ("" which-func-format " "))))
(setq mode-line-misc-info
            ;; We remove Which Function Mode from the mode line, because it's mostly
            ;; invisible here anyway.
            (assq-delete-all 'which-func-mode mode-line-misc-info))
```

Comment: It might be useful to summarize the blog post to guard against link rot.

Comment: I am quite confident that this is not the method that I was using before, but it does a pretty good job of guessing the current function.  It took me a long time to make it work though because I couldn't read the text in the header line due to the font color. Changing the `header-line` face had no effect.  I had to rummage through the sources for `which-function-mode` to figure out that there is a special face called `which-func` that is applied as a text property. :\